# Passing variable from a clicked link - jQuery to Servlet using AJAX

Tags: java, jquery

I can get the value of a link using jQuery but I am unable to pass it to a servlet, I need that to work on SQL statements.

Main.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id ="data">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Case Number</th>
                <th>Student Number</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Middlename</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Violation</th>
            </tr>
        <%
             ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)request.getAttribute("resultset");
             String str = "";
             while(rs.next())
             {
                 str += "<tr><td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td><td><a href = \"viewStudentRecords\" class = \"data1\">"+rs.getString(2)+"</a></td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(5)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(6)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(7)+"</td>";
             }

             out.println(str);%>
        </table>
    </div>



    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script>

         $(document).ready(function()
         {
            $(function()
            {
                alert("hello");
            });

            $('.data1').click(function(link) 
                {
                    var number = $(this).text();
                    alert(number);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/viewStudentRecords",
                        data: {studNo:number},
                        success: function() {
                          console.log("Success!!");
                        },

                      });
                });
            });

    </script>

</body>
```

When I click a link, `alert(number)` works.

viewStudentRecords.java

```
protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String studNo = request.getParameter("studNo");
    out.println(studNo);
    }
```

But the servlet returns `null`

I know that `<% %>` is not advisable but I have no knowledge about JSTL.
Any help would be nice.

Comment: `request.getParameter("txt")`? - What is `txt`?  Isn't the parameter called `studNo`?

Comment: You're creating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. Change it to a `class` and use jQuery to select by that class. Also, change `$(link.target)` to `$(this)`, and remove the nested document.ready handler.

Comment: changed to `request.getParameter("number")` shouldn't it contain the variable from jQuery?

Comment: also changed from id to class and `$(link.target)` to `$(this)`

Comment: @jaxxj: Why did you change it to `"number"`?  The value is being sent as `"studNo"`: `data: {studNo:number}`  You have to retrieve the value using the same key that you use to send the value.

Comment: changed to `"studNo"` in servlet, still getting no luck

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use "viewStudentRecords" @ two places in href & in Ajax request so probably you get null because of this. First Ajax request calls & then href request get fired & you get null value. Try to use either href or Ajax.